# React-highcharts: I have "renderer" problem and I need a way to update "state" upon function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm facing a scope problem with `state` within a `react` app.

I'm adding some buttons to my `chart` component at the top of high chart component.
Now, what I'd like is to add those buttons inside chart space (under title) to save some space.

The solution I found on older posts and forum was to use this method:

```js
chart.events.render(this.renderer.button.add())
```

I'm not sure if this method is deprecated in favor of `SVGRenderer`.

My approach was

```js
chart: {
    events: {
      render() {
        let chart = this;

        console.log("this chart", chart);
        const handlePeriodClick = (periodType) => {
          const filteredData = chart.options.data.map((option) =>({
            ...option,
            data: option.data.filter((item) =>
              moment(item[0]).diff(moment(item[0]).endOf(periodType), 'days') === 0)
          }));
          // need to acces states from React within Highchart.chart component
          this.setState({ filteredData });
        };

        chart.renderer.button('D',10, 55)
          .on('click', function () {
            handlePeriodClick('day');
          })
          .add();
        chart.renderer.button('W',35, 55)
          .on('click', function () {
            handlePeriodClick('week');
          })
          .add();
        chart.renderer.button('M',60, 55)
          .on('click', function () {
            handlePeriodClick('month');
          })
          .add();
      }
    }
  },
```

I need to update `state` inside that function call so as to reflect a `data` update. Here is a working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-button-inside-chart-3s99u?file=/src/CustomGUIChart.js).

I've also tried to use `SVGRenderer` instead of `renderer` but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of happens in your demo and I don't understand clearly what do you want to achieve, but it seems that **render** callback is never triggered - this `console.log("this chart", chart);` don't show up.

Below are my advices on how to change state in the custom functions in the rendered buttons.

1. Define the function and variable to attach this outside the scope.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-1fm35?file=/demo.jsx

2. If you want to only change the data you can do it also by using the **series.update** Highcharts feature - there will be no scope problem.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-11mpt

Comment: I forgot to call `Highcharts.setOptions(Highcharts.chart)` on my demo, that's why the console log wasn't being called (also all renderer block), I have just fixed that. Also, what is the `highcharts/highcharts-more` for?

Comment: `highcharts-more` it is a module which extends basic Highcharts core. Some of the chart types requires it, like: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.columnpyramid